# How FireBug & Firefox works?

Tags: firebug

I have several Question about Firefox and Firebug working mechanisms.
i have a page in my doman  : mydomain.com
i want to load an external html page in my page from : externalhtml.com
i can't using frame and iframe.(because externalhtml.com server send additional x-option-frame:SAMEORIGIN header to requested file header and html page not loaded in iframe or frame.)

i tested some other tags. (i just want to grap source code of html file and x-options-frame only affected on iframe and frame tags!)
with  tag the source code of mydoman.com page is:

but when i inspect page with firebug the full source of html.html loaded under script tag (like tree drop down object )

for  tag  have similar condition.script not loaded in source of page but fully loaded in firebug inspector.

but when i use iframe there is nothing in firebug inspector. (server dont send anything to mydomain.com )

my question is that how firebug works? how it grab content of a script and load in it's windows.
is any way to do this by jQuery Or AJAX(i tested it but i have problem with same domain restrictions implemented on XMLHttpRequest ....) or ...

really sorry for bad English.
thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already solved your problem but in case you haven't...  The browser is probably preventing a Cross Origin Resource Sharing.  I had a similar problem that I fixed by making changes to the server to allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests).  You can't 'fix' this from the client end.  The server has to allow it.